# I have dockerVolume which has a json file.Am looking to print the json using some docker commands or running a shell script

Tags: docker, containers

I have a dockerVolume outputVolume,which has a json file.Am working to print the json File to console either using any docker commands or shell script.

i have tried to "Echo"ing the file.
Tried opening the file ,am not looking to increase the docker size by any means.

Comment: Can you provide some information of how are you running exactly the container? the command you are using to mount the volume or if you are using docker-compoer?

Comment: am using the "docker run -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/outputResultVolume/_data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/outputResultVolume/_data ImageName  for mounting.am able to see the json files in the mounted volume.I would only need to print the contents of the file to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to execute some commands inside your container you need to know what distro is based on and what shell you have to know the commands you have available.

Assuming you are using an image based on debian/ubuntu you can execute some commands without needing to be logged inside the container by running `docker exec`, for example:

```
docker exec <conainer id> <command>
```

If you whant to see the content of a file generated inside your container you can run:

```
docker exec <continer id> cat <path to your file>
```

If you want to have an interactive terminal inside the container you can run:

```
docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash
```

Comment: can we skip the containerId ?docker exec ,when placing the container id am getting the result.but i do have the file path in the docker volume.

Comment: am able to print using the suggestion you provided(docker exec <continer id> cat <path to your file>).but looking to customize with file path alone.

Comment: No, you cannot avoid the use of the container ID using docker command alone, if you are looking for a more easy way to manage your local docker you can use docker-compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 1):

You need to [start a new container with the volume attached](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume).  Note that the content in `/var/lib/docker` is usually considered "private to Docker" and you shouldn't access it directly; also note that there's no requirement to use the same file path on both sides of a bind-mount `docker run -v` option.

For the example in your comment, I might write

```
docker run -v outputResultVolume:/data busybox cat /data/whatever.json
```

While the Docker documentation is fairly enthusiastic about named volumes, I've generally found host bind mounts to be operationally simpler.  (For things like database storage, in a development environment, where you never need to look at or back up the volume files, named volumes work fine.)  If you're running short-lived processes where file I/O is the main operation, you also might consider whether an OS-native packaging system (RPM, dpkg, Homebrew, ...) might still make it easy to reproducibly run your package without adding any of this operational complexity.